# How to get back console of a running gdb process?

Tags: gdb

I had attached gdb to a long running process(>25 hours). To manage the session, I used screen on my Ubuntu machine. I could get the session back. I got back the gdb console. But on continuing I saw my process throw `SIGABRT` and exit followed up by other process exit messages.

```
[New LWP 122]
[Thread debugging using libthread_db enabled]
Using host libthread_db library "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libthread_db.so.1".
0x00007fe8ef29ea15 in futex_abstimed_wait_cancelable (private=0, abstime=0x7ffc8c628420, expected=0, futex_word=0x7fe8e6378640) at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/
linux/futex-internal.h:205
205     ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/futex-internal.h: No such file or directory.
(gdb) c
Continuing.
(gdb) [Thread 0x7be8d8bfd700 (LWP 48) exited]

Thread 32 "my-process" received signal SIGABRT, Aborted.
[Switching to Thread 0x7be8d2bbd700 (LWP 60)]
0x00007fe8eece4428 in __GI_raise (sig=sig@entry=6) at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/raise.c:54
54      ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/raise.c: No such file or directory.
(gdb) c
Continuing.
Couldn't get registers: No such process.
Couldn't get registers: No such process.
Couldn't get registers: No such process.
(gdb) [Thread 0x7be8b67ff700 (LWP 119) exited]
[Thread 0x7be8b49fe700 (LWP 122) exited]
...
```

I am not able to get the gdb console after that. Though I see a process running when I run `ps -ef`

```
root       133     0  1 Jan14 ?        00:26:09 gdb --pid=23
```

How do get back the console for this gdb process? I wanted to see the backtrace.
Or is there a better way to attach gdb to a long running process ?